# Is there a way to remove NuGet dlls from the output folder of a project?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, nuget

The following is within Visual Studio 2015 update 3 using project.json instead of packages.config.

Here is the scenario - I have one solution with multiple projects. One project (projectA) references a NuGet package using project.json. ProjectA is a class library. Another project (projectB) within the same solution has a project reference to the first project (projectA). ProjectA does not release any types from the NuGet to projectB, but when projectB builds the output directory is filled with the NuGet references.

This causes projectB to have the same build time as projectA. I am assuming this is due to copying the same dlls from the NuGet to projectB.

Am I correct with this assumption? Is it possible to keep the NuGet dlls confined to projectA?

My goal - have projectB only reference projectA, not the NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. It's because the `Compiler` compiles those referenced projects as well, as in your case `ProjectA`, when it compiles your base `Project B`. This is because the executabel file (`*.exe`) needs those `*.dll` if it runs, because it **references** and **not contains** it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Much appreciated.